# Where can I find the code for 'salespricehtml' in NetSuite?

Tags: schema, netsuite, schema.org, microdata

Where can I find the code for 'salespricehtml' or 'addtocarthtml' in NetSuite?

I am trying to add Schema.org Microdata on my website's product pages, especially for the price, but the quantity amounts and prices are being displayed on the website using the tag/name 'salespricehtml' like so `<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','salespricehtml')%>`.  If you can help, it would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Any update on this, Ron? I'm looking for salesPriceHTML as well, but for a different reason. The answer below doesn't actually answer your original question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <h3>          
              <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="AUD">$</span><span itemprop="price" content="<%=getCurrentAttribute("item","salesPrice")%>">
                <script language="javascript">
                  salesPriceRaw('<%=getCurrentAttribute("item","salesPrice")%>');                   
                </script>
              </span>
              <small>
                <script language="javascript">
                  gstHtml('<%=getCurrentAttribute("item","salestaxcode")%>');
                </script>
              </small>
              <span itemprop="availability" content="In stock"></span>
            </h3>
          </div>
```

With the following script in the head to format tax info and comply with microdata standards as closely as possible:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function salesPriceRaw (salesPrice) {
    var price = salesPrice.replace('$', '');
    document.write(price);
  }
  function gstHtml (gst) {
    if (gst == 'GST:TS-AU') {
    document.write(' + GST ');
    } else {
      document.write('(GST Exempt) ');
    }
  }
</script>
```

It's a hack really, but it works. In essence you should remove the html part from your getCurrentAttribute tag. Hope this helps!